# How to place unix commands - copy files from Windows to Unix directory/ Unix to Windows in VBScript?

Tags: windows, unix, vbscript

I am not sure how to place the Unix commands in a VBScript file.

I am trying to write a code in VBScript where we can copy our files from our Windows folder to Unix directory.

Here writing files in the our Unix directory requires username and password.

I explored and found that we can use SCP command this way to copy files:

```
scp d:/folders/hello.txt /abc_st/batchrepo/inbox
# I am still exploring for copying files from Unix to Windows
```

And for Username/Password, I found that we can use sshpass command like below before scp command:

```
sshpass -p "your password" 
# I still have to explore on this as I cant see the place for username.
```

Could someone please suggest how can I place these commands in a VBScript file.

I'll be placing this VBScript into an HTML file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support SSH by itself, so you need some kind of `scp` utility for copying files from a Windows host to a Unix host, for instance [`pscp.exe`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), or the ssh package in [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Assuming you're using `pscp.exe` you can run the client by shelling out like this:

```vb
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "C:\path\to\pscp.exe -pw PASS D:\folders\hello.txt unixhost:/abc_st/batchrepo/inbox", 0, True
```

Make sure to quote paths if they contain spaces:

```vb
Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run qq("C:\path\to\pscp.exe") & " -pw PASS " & qq("D:\folders\hello.txt") _
  & " unixhost:/abc_st/batchrepo/inbox", 0, True
```